# How to change foreign Key restraint on Dataset with Table Adapter

Tags: asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a `Dataset` that has 3 `TablesAdapters` linked together (both the relationships and foreign-keys came over from the DB design).  I'm trying now to to bind the `TableAdapter` with the foreign keys on it, I get the following:

> "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."

so after a little digging, I found that it doesn't like that I have Identical foreign keys on the `TableAdapter` (even though the DB contraints are OK with this).

How to I get my `DataSet` (or the `TableAdpapter`) to only look at the primary key of the table as a contraint?

Comment: Show the schema(the DataSet) and the code where you fill the tables. The order is important if you fill them separately for each table.

Comment: Sidenote: You can use the debugger to see the reason for the constraint exception. Set a breakpoint right before your `TableAdapter.Fill` statement. Execute this line in the quick watch window what causes the exception in the debugger. Then you can execute following line to get the error-rows(in the quick-watch window): `DataTable.GetErrors()`. Then you look into these rows at their `RowError` property to see what actually causes the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so 5 seconds after I post this I find the answer (isn't that how it always works?)

The problem was that I added a table adapter that queried from my multiple tables, not just a single table.  This tableAdapter looks like it just "decided" what columns to use for unique Contraints.

To fix the issue, I had to go into the Dataset designer and search for "UniqueConstraint" until I found the one that was using two foreign key columns of the restraint instead of the one primary key.